# Sharepoint 2013 and SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 2

Tags: sql-server, service-pack-2

I've tried to research this, but I'm not seeing anything relevant to installing Service Pack 2 for SQL Server 2012.

Our DBA's want to apply this to out SharePoint 2012 SQL Server, but I can't find anything that shows that it's supported.

Has anyone installed SQL Server 2012 SP2 on a SharePoint 2013 farm? Any catch outs? Any articles that show it's supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is any known issue with SQL Server 2012 SP2...other than this SP may have fixed some bugs :-) We have been using SP2 with SP 2013 with no issues.

Could not find any Technet article specifically mentioning SP2 with SP 2013 (I suppose they aren't updated yet) other than this [blog post](https://habaneroconsulting.com/insights/SharePoint-SQL-Server-Support-Matrix#.VN5Y_PnF-Ys).

Also it is always a good idea to test this out in your DEV or QA farms (just in case).

Hope this helps!